# How to show particular row in table of ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I want to show table of two rows in which upper row is column names and lower row shows the sum of all the values in SSRS report when I have used the table it's showing more than one rows but actually I wanted to show in one row. what shall i need to do. I am using SSRS 2008 in visual studio 2013. Here is the snapshot,[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your data in either a detail row or a grouped row. You will need to create a row outside the group below the last group. Then put your sum(Field!Data.Value) expressions in that last row that is not in a group or detail row.